# Place Read More link next to the text if the text has more than 3 lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to show a read more link if text has more than 3 lines. I am using line-clamp property to restrict number of lines to 3. I have 2 problems:

1. How do I hide read more link if text has less than 3 lines.
2. How do place read more link at the end of last line instead of next line. Like below

   This is the last line before show read more link. The line ends in ellipsis...[Read
   More](https://someplace.com)

Right now i am placing text in span and read more at the end of span but in case that last line end in middle of span than i get white space between text and link.

How can i resolve this issue. Any help would be appriciated. Thank you.